# Action Script 3. Spawn objects in different time

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, object, actionscript, time

I'm creating game where falling 4 different objects from the sky and need to destroy them by clicking mouse button. My problem is that all 4 objects spawns at the same time. I  need to make that randomly spawned all 4, but not in the same time and after player have 200 points I need to make that spawned and falled more objects. (I have working counter which counting points).
And one more thing if you know how to make that objects not spawned on one other. 
I mean:

Bad spawn.

[image: bad spawns]

Here is my constant vars:

```
public static const GRAVITY:Number = 3;
public static const HIT_TOLERANCE:Number = 50;  

//Powerup
public static const APPLE_END_Y:Number = 640;
public static const APPLE_SPAWN_CHANCE:Number = 0.02; //per frame per second
public static const APPLE_START_Y:Number = 110;
public static const APPLE_SPAWN_START_X:Number = 50;
public static const APPLE_SPAWN_END_X:Number = 500;

//Scoring
public static const PLAYER_START_SCORE:Number = 0;
public static const SCORE_PER_APPLE:Number = 10;
```

Here is part of my code:

```
 public function startGame()
        {
            speed = C.PLAYER_SPEED;
            gravity = C.GRAVITY;
            score = C.PLAYER_START_SCORE;
            randomChance = C.APPLE_SPAWN_CHANCE;
        tol = C.HIT_TOLERANCE;
            apples = new Array();
            mcGameStage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,update);

        }       

        private function update(evt:Event)
        {

            //Spawn new apples
            if (Math.random() < randomChance)
            {
                //spawn x  coordinates
                var newPirmas = new Pirmas();
                newPirmas.x = Math.random() * C.APPLE_SPAWN_END_X + C.APPLE_SPAWN_START_X;
                var newAntras = new Antras();
                newAntras.x = Math.random() * C.APPLE_SPAWN_END_X + C.APPLE_SPAWN_START_X;
                var newTrecias = new Trecias();
                newTrecias.x = Math.random() * C.APPLE_SPAWN_END_X + C.APPLE_SPAWN_START_X;
                var newApple = new Apple();
                newApple.x = Math.random() * C.APPLE_SPAWN_END_X + C.APPLE_SPAWN_START_X;
                //spawn y coordinates
                newPirmas.y = C.APPLE_START_Y;
                newAntras.y = C.APPLE_START_Y;
                newTrecias.y = C.APPLE_START_Y;
                newApple.y = C.APPLE_START_Y;
                apples.push(newPirmas);
                apples.push(newAntras);
                apples.push(newTrecias);
                apples.push(newApple);
                newPirmas.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick);
                newAntras.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick);
                newTrecias.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick);
                newApple.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick);

                mcGameStage.addChildAt(newPirmas,0);
                mcGameStage.addChildAt(newAntras,0);
                mcGameStage.addChildAt(newTrecias,0);
                mcGameStage.addChildAt(newApple,0);
            }           
            //Move Apples
            for (var i = apples.length-1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                apples[i].y += gravity;

                if (apples[i].y > C.APPLE_END_Y)
                {
                    mcGameStage.removeChild(apples[i]);

                    apples.splice(i,1);
                     m_iLives--;
                     if (!m_iLives)
        {
            trace("Game Over");

            // newApple.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick);
            break;
        }
                }
            }           
            txtScore.text = String(score);
        }
        function onClick(evt:MouseEvent):void{
        var apples = evt.target;        
        apples.visible = false;
    apples = tol;   
        score += C.SCORE_PER_APPLE; 
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public function startGame()
{
    speed = C.PLAYER_SPEED;
    gravity = C.GRAVITY;
    score = C.PLAYER_START_SCORE;
    randomChance = C.APPLE_SPAWN_CHANCE;
    tol = C.HIT_TOLERANCE;
    apples = [];
    itemsToSpawn = [];
    mcGameStage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,update);

    nextSpawn:Number = 0;

}       

private function update(evt:Event)
{
    //Spawn new apples
    if (Math.random() < randomChance)
    {
        //spawn x  coordinates
        var newPirmas = new Pirmas();
        newPirmas.x = Math.random() * C.APPLE_SPAWN_END_X + C.APPLE_SPAWN_START_X;
        var newAntras = new Antras();
        newAntras.x = Math.random() * C.APPLE_SPAWN_END_X + C.APPLE_SPAWN_START_X;
        var newTrecias = new Trecias();
        newTrecias.x = Math.random() * C.APPLE_SPAWN_END_X + C.APPLE_SPAWN_START_X;
        var newApple = new Apple();
        newApple.x = Math.random() * C.APPLE_SPAWN_END_X + C.APPLE_SPAWN_START_X;
        //spawn y coordinates
        newPirmas.y = C.APPLE_START_Y;
        newAntras.y = C.APPLE_START_Y;
        newTrecias.y = C.APPLE_START_Y;
        newApple.y = C.APPLE_START_Y;

        newPirmas.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick);
        newAntras.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick);
        newTrecias.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick);
        newApple.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick);

        //add items to itemsToAdd
        itemsToAdd.push(newPirmas, newAntras, newTrecias, newApple);

    }           

    //Move Apples
    for (var i = apples.length-1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        apples[i].y += gravity;

        if (apples[i].y > C.APPLE_END_Y)
        {
            mcGameStage.removeChild(apples[i]);

            apples.splice(i,1);
            m_iLives--;
            if (!m_iLives)
            {
                trace("Game Over");

                // newApple.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick);
                break;
            }
        }
    }           

    txtScore.text = String(score);


    if( itemsToSpawn.length > 0 && getTimeout() > nextSpawn  )
    {
        var item:DisplayObject = itemsToAdd.shift();
        apples.push(item);
        mcGameStage.addChild(item);
        nextSpawn = getTimeout() + Math.random() * 4000;
    }

}

function onClick(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    var apples = event.currentTarget;        
    apples.visible = false;
    apples = tol;   
    score += C.SCORE_PER_APPLE; 

    if(score % 100 == 0)
    {
        gravity += 10;
    }
}
```

Comment: you mean add them add at a on occupied space? This depends on your game engine. If you create a grid, you could check a given cell if it is occupied by an object. But this goes way beyond your question.

Comment: Sorry, I want to ask you how to put all the items which I want spawn to array `itemsToSpawn`?

Comment: Thank you for answer, when I use this I got 2 errors: on this line `if( itemsToSpawn.length > 0 && Math.random * 3 % 3 == 1 )` error: `1067: Implicit coercion of a value of type Function to an unrelated type Number.` and on this line `var item:DisplayObject = itemsToSpawn.unshift();` error: `1067: Implicit coercion of a value of type uint to an unrelated type flash.display:DisplayObject.`

Comment: sorry. Had no time to compile it. Math.random() ;), and itemsToAdd.shift(). I updated the code.

Comment: I think you meant `itemsToSpawn.shift()` ? And when I use this code, now I don't get any errors, but objects not spawning at all.

Comment: If I use `if( itemsToSpawn.length > 0 && Math.random() * 3 % 3)` instead `if( itemsToSpawn.length > 0 && Math.random() * 3 % 3 == 1 )` objects spawning but always they spawning all 4, difference 1 millisecond between they spawns one by one

Comment: For example: I need to make that It spawn 1 second obejct 1, after 2 seconds object 2, after 1 second object 4, etc. It must randomly, not always all 4 one by one

Comment: Sorry man. Ok updated it again. What the code now does (or is suposed to be doing :)) checks if the current timeout is greater than the next spawn time. If so, spawn an item and reset the next spawn time. 4 sec max. I`m sorry if something is not quite correct but I have little time. But I like to help :)

Comment: Thank you for help, but now I got error: `1180: Call to a possibly undefined method getTimeout.`

Comment: shit I`m sorry. its getTimer() and you have to import it maybe. import flash.utils.getTimer; Switching between programming languages and private libraries is not helping :)

Comment: Thank you very much! Now It's working. Could you help me, how to make that after every 100 points reached It started falling a bit faster? Just if you can :) And where I noticed about "Bad spawn" in my first question (image - Bad Spawn) could you help me with this too? THank you.

Comment: You need to change the gravity value over time. More gravity means faster falling. Two the second question, eather ask a new one or use Cereal answer. This is a start. I would check regions.

Comment: Ok, thank you, could you show me what line I need to add to increase gravity after every 100 points?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30843/discussion-between-larusso-and-rimant-baltiejt)

Answer (score 0):

In your update code, you're checking a single time for a random value to be less than randomChance, and when it is, you spawn 4 apples.

If you want them to spawn at different times, you would call them one at a time. I would make a function to create a randomly placed apple, and call that whenever your if statement is satisfied.

Eg:

```
private function update(evt:Event){
    if(Math.random() < randomValue){
        createApple();
    }
```

Where createApple() would create a new apple, position it, add it to the array, and add it to the stage.

If you're trying to create a different apple each time, you can put the different types in an array and iterate through it as you create new apples.

EG.

```
private function createApple(){
    ...
    var newApple = appleToSpawn[currentApple]
    ...
}
```

Where appleToSpawn is an array of apple objects, and currentApple is an index of which apple you're currently on.

Alternatively, you could do a series of comparisons to a random number, and spawn a different apple depending on which condition is satisfied.

As for making sure they don't overlap, you can keep a history of their spawn points, and change how you get their random X value. Just iterate through the array of previous X values, and make sure the new one isn't within (oldX + (width/2)).

Now for spawning more than 4 as you get more points, just change your randomChance to a bigger number as you go. If it's a bigger number, you'll satisfy your conditional statement more often, therefor spawning more apples.